# Matrix for orthogonal projection with respect to ordered and canonical bases

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, transformation

Orthogonal projection onto the line $y = 2x$ gives a linear transformation $T: R2 → R2$ such that

$$T(1,2) = (1,2)$$ and $$T(−2,1) = (0,0)$$

Then the matrix of T with respect to the ordered basis

$$B = \{(1, 2), (−2, 1)\}$$ 
and the standard basis 
$$S = \{(1, 0), (0, 1)\}$$ 
is?

Attempt to solve for ordered? (or is it for standard?):
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix}*T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
solving for T:

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & -2\\ 
2 & 1
\end{bmatrix} ^{-1} *\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
2 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$

$$T=\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0\\ 
0 & 0
\end{bmatrix}$$
when I check it geometrically (for projection), it always gives me the zeros for the second coordinate, however is it supposed to be perpendicular projection of the point on the line y=2x.

Can you kindly tell me what's going wrong with it?
Or my solution is completely incorrect? 
And what about getting T in the standard canonical basis? is it just the matrix T multiplied by Transformation matrix of B base to S base: $$P_{BS}$$ i.e. $$T*P_{BS}$$

Comment: It looks like you have the correct matrix wrt the ordered basis. It's supposed to always give you zeros in the second coordinate since the second basis vector maps to (0,0).

Comment: To find the matrix of the transformation with respect to the standard basis, just calculate what the basis vectors $(1,0)$ and $(0,1)$ map to, and these will be the column vectors of T.